# what client side javascript cache library would you recommend?

Tags: javascript, caching, client-side

I'm looking for a client-side javascript cache library

Ideally, this is the feature list I'd like to have

- no dependencies
- simple
- time expiration support
- use localStorage if available, and fallback to array
- actively developed

I've found a few options, but they don't seem to be particularly active

Related questions at SO are a bit ancient too...

https://github.com/monsur/jscache (this is the most promising one)

http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-cache-provider

[What JavaScript cache can you recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322694/what-javascript-cache-can-you-recommend)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoc/

https://github.com/jeromeetienne/MicroCache.js/blob/master/microcache.js

Comment: What is it you want to cache?

Comment: `actively developed`?  how much active development does a utility that works require?

Comment: I want to cache some ajax calls, that I have to process to create some javascript objects... And an app object in which I save the user information (permissions, menu options, etc...)

Comment: @charlietfl things don't have to be actively developed but it's nice if there's an active community using it and supporting new users.

Answer (score 4):

we made a library for Javascript.

- no dependencies
- simple
- time expiration support
- use localStorage and sessionStorage
- and it has more features.

you can look from here

https://github.com/giraysam/boomerang-cache

Comment: Downvoters should explain their reason for downvoting. Otherwise how can we know what they found `wrong` about this answer.

Comment: thanks @PaulRooney you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 3):

i just made simple js lib for caching. It support array and localStorage

https://github.com/hoangnd25/cacheJS